# Acidic Environment and Rust

Tags: electrochemistry

I'm trying to understand why in an acidic environment, rust increases. The explanations I have seen so far basically have the following,

> "In acidic environments the cathode for the rusting of iron changes to
>   $O_{2(g)}+4H^+ _{(aq)} + 4e^- \rightarrow 2H_2 O_{(l)}$. The anode
>   reaction remains $Fe_{(s)} \rightarrow Fe^{2+} + 2e^-$. The  cell
>   value increases as the cathodic process is lower in the
>   electrochemical series, producing a more effective electrochemical
>   cell, accelerating corrosion rate."

Though I don't understand why in acidic environments the cathode reaction changes? These are some of the explanations I've read

- In normal oxygenated conditions hydronium ions increase the electrode potential of the reduction of oxygen making it a better oxidant.
- In acidic environments the reduction of oxygen proceeds more rapidly. (This doesn't seem to really explain it)

**Question**
Why in acidic environments does the cathode reaction for the rusting of iron change?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35245/why-is-acidic-hydrogen-peroxide-a-potent-oxidizer